# How to make table of contents in sidebar using CSS?

Tags: html, css, tableofcontents

I would like to make a webpage with a sidebar table of contents (TOC) like this:

https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html

The TOC is currently at the top of the HTML page this way:

```html
<h2>Table of Contents</h2>
<div id="text-table-of-contents">
  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    ...
    <li><a href="#orgbdecee3">Topic 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I create a CSS file so that such a TOC appears as a sidebar?

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You are expected to invest your best effort to solve the problem by yourself first. Then, if you fail, search the web for why it might fail. If you've done all that and still didn't succeed, come back here, show your best attempt, explain how it fails and what you expect instead.

Comment: Have you tried giving it a css class `.work-as-I-want { position: ideal; all-browsers-and-resolutions: yes; }`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use position `absolute` and `fixed` to solve our problem.

```css
.grid{
position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  color:#fff;
  
  
}

.one{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
width:25%;
background:#333;
}
.two{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:25%;
bottom:0;
width:75%;
background:#999;
height:120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">aaa</div>
  <div class="two">aaa</div>
</div>
```